# How to mark a Sybase ASE DB as offline for startup

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

I need to load a database dump into a target database, on Sybase ASE 16. In order to do that, the target database must be offline. Sybase ASE doesn't have a command to put a database offline, so my only possibility is to stop the DB server and restart it, taking care that the target database is not brought online during startup. This is my question: which command/option do I need to set so that a specific database is not brought online at server startup? I couldn't find it in the official documentation :-(

Comment: I don't agree with your statement "target database must be offline" - It must not be used by anyone else and you need to have exclusive access in order to start loading. That's the only criteria. if database is offline - how will you load it?

Comment: You mean to set it in single user mode? I could try that. For your other comment, loading a DB from offline status has worked in the past.

Comment: It seems you are using restoring and not-online database interchangeably with offline. for testing purpose, you can create one dummy database - dump the data out and load it. Just ensure that there is no active connection to that dummy database before loading and you should be able to load it.

Comment: You may check link --> https://answers.sap.com/questions/11748141/database-in-use-a-user-with-system-administrator-s.html

Comment: Regarding offline database, please read details here --> http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1570/html/sag2/sag2534.htm

Comment: The target database **does not** need to be 'offline'; the target database **does** need to have no active users; have you tried loading the dump into the target and if so what happened?  if you received an error then please post the (complete) error message; if you're having problems getting rid of an active user in the db then you may want to consider [dbcc dbreboot](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBASE/DBCC+dbreboot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Learning_DBAdmin for correcting me: the database does not have to be offline, the load process was failing due to remaining connections of other users on this target database. After killing the offending connections and putting the database in single user mode, it was possible to load a dump into it.